# Voltage of parallel components (RLC circuit)

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

Say we have the circuit above.

The 6 A current is applied at t=0.

I'm trying to get the voltage across the inductor to get di/dt.

If I run this circuit in LTspice, it will show a voltage of 30mv across all nodes. I'm not really sure how I get the 30mv. I was thinking that since the inductor would be a short circuit at t < 0, the voltage across it will be 0V, hence di/dt would also be 0. But I'm confused about LTspicee's 30mv result.

Comment: LTspice does assume some series resistance for all inductors to simplify the simulation IIRC. It could be that which you are seeing. If your current source does not have any di/dt then neither will your inductor.

Comment: Thought so since when I do the calculation for the current through the inductor and comparing it to ltspice's, there are some discrepancy but they are really close.

Comment: LTspice must have transient analysis...but Falstad scan simulate this in a minute

Comment: The coincidence of 3 A being applied for t<0, and the stray voltage beginning with a 3 does suggest a 'nice round number' 10 mohm series resistance in L1.

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/y3mhfgzd

Comment: @Batt: I answered another question from you similar to this one. The link is https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/528128/22676

Comment: @DirceuRodriguesJr Oh i didn't notice that one. Thanks, ill check it out! I already finished that problem, im gonna check it with your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPICE, in general, when no special considerations apply to the simulation card, tries to solve the circuit prior to simulation, i.e. it considers that the circuit has been running since the dawn of time, has had time to settle all the transients, and when the user presses "run", all that's left is the steady-state.

This is what happened here: you set the simulation card as `.tran 10m`, which has no special flags or settings, thus LTspice first tried to determine the steady-state before running the simulation.

Since you are interested in the dynamics of the circuit, then you have to tell that to the simulator, since it can't read minds. One of the conditions you mention is that the current source is switched on at t=0. I'll assume that the voltage source is DC only. You could add the `uic` flag, but that would force `V1` to start from zero, too. It's more useful to modify the current source, only.

With these in mind, this is how you can try to model the circuit:

[image: test]

Notice how I've changed `I1` to be a step source: `PWL(0 0 1u 6)`. That means at t=0 it's 0, and in the course of 1 us it switches to a 6 A value. You cannot use a zero rise (or fall) time, since that would be a physical impossibility; no simulator would accept that. Those conditions are mathematical abstractions for the easyness of calculation (like the Dirac pulse). That's why there has to be a value for the rising time. There's also no need to exaggerate and make it 1 ps, partly because the differences in the output will be minimal, and also because all the SPICE engines use machine precision (usually `double`) to crunch numbers, so using extreme differences (1 ps vs fractions of a second time constants) might cause the matrix to be ill-conditioned.

If you say you need a derivative, you can right-click on `V(x)` in the waveform window and modify it to `d(V(x))`. Be careful: the waveform compression (default on) will affect the outcome. To turn off waveform compression add this to your schematic (reminder: press `S`): `.opt plotwinsize=0`. It will increase the size of the `.raw` file, but for this case, it shouldn't matter.

One other thing to know is that LTspice adds a default 1 mOhm series resitance to the inductors. This can be set to zero by right-clicking on the inductor and setting `Rser=0` (or in the `Control Panel > Hacks! > Supply a min. ...`, which would make this setting permanent). One of the reasons for this is that many people added a voltage source straight across the inductors and then got `voltage loop` errors. There are other parasitics that are added behind the scenes, so if you really want to make the LC elements as ideal as possible, right-click on them and set to zero all the fields (except `peak current` for L, and `voltage rating` and `RMS current rating` for C -- thise are decorative, mostly).

Comment: Holy. This is very helpful to my future simulations as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

L/Rs = T = ~ 4H / 10 Ohms = 400 ms  the (Reset) linear asymptote for [voltage and current.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YwjArCATGSB2WS1ICwA4CBOPAZh3iRBxJFghyQCgB3ZMPZHCJeANk%206MATiBIoByPhIh0Wk-kgKjxijmGFUxE6pVXgq6gObzkSnvxJgc4RgHkQ8TBPg5ruCB8YA3E3vPT9LlEPfVR4RgBLZW4lMW4giF5GAGNRPDcgknTTNVoAUwBaNUhCWCIGMDR8SyQScIAbByd3Jt0lehA8SAJHLNxcBkc5R10gnWk5cZasjM9WGYk4ifmVWOy9dXn1pSn2yd43JRGc2n3Djl21Ri4af3xW2icIeAB9A5ewF%20oXF8JeD%20gMDAhDQvD4PA%20L1gLwAagB7ACuABdrmBblJMBxjrBCJQIIQ3jhIdReNC8J9MN1IUhfi8SC8AJIAHQAzgAKAAyAEpGEA)

Now you add all the other descriptors measure peak cap current, 40R current and list below.  Point  reset, stop and measure on the run, change the slow speed simulation or go faster if your CPU can handle it

[For more fun watch with auto vertical max scale, change scroll speeds, stop/reset](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YwjArCATGSB2WS1ICwA4CBOPAZh3iRBxJFghyQCgB3ZMPZHCJeANk%206MATiBIoByPhIh0Wk-kgKjxijmGFUxE6pVXgq6gObzkSnvxJgc4RgHkQ8TBPg5ruCB8YA3E3vPT9LlEPfVR4RgBLZW4lMW4giF5GAGNRPDcgknTTNVoAUwBaNWgYGDxeXjQCdksK8ySAGwcnd2bdJXoQPEhCXt68QlheR3gwNDlHXSCdaTkZ1qyMz1ZFiTjZlZVY7L11FZ2leY653jclSZzaE7OOI7VGLhp-Aq0LrQh4AH1Tz7BPzBcvF%200FgXCQsFghDQ8EGsGhpC%20qFKsF%20-0%20ADUAPYAVwALg8wE8pPg2iBCPwIIRvjhUQD4CRgcjPt0%20v0BoMcL1eCi-khPlSGQBJAA6AGcABQAGQAlASifw4fwLihcgyfn8AeRGXBtYTRhReiQoWhCEaYai%20QyhWLxVwAEqyx4mTAcC5DEJ4am0nhapE6v1gHmfPme62i5IAQwADowgA)

- takes 2 Reset clicks after a stop

When the rise time changes faster than the X sampling rate (options>other options, you get weird errors on Icap.

[Now look again on a faster scale](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsCmC0AcIBMYB0B2AjE9SAs8hAnPAMx6RIh6kiYR5IBQA7smIvhEpAGzJ5uTAE4hSKAdz6TwdMK2TSkhMROWJ5omlS7VxyFQ3kBzRf3VmxYPOCYB5KNhmQ8N3RHkA3SxZ7nBskZWgeCokEwAlqrcKuLcARC8TADGYvBuAaTpBhp0cIhYqESklAR84nxkTAA2jjoBkE4WDKFgHGBEkKS88Egk9GC86PAKjfUM%20u4K2jJZGR4Kc7NqCYtqsdnNi5sqM1tseLxuKmM5dNNHZ3uGTIK0fiCw%20qf6EJAA%20kfvYO-YLrzvQpEYFkXi8FxgJBIcTfVBtMCYb6-d4ANQA9gBXAAutzA92kBDqICI-AgRE%20eCRfy6sPhiLQbXgYEg8EgCME6F45CIPCRSHe5NI7wAkgAdADOAAoADIASlx%20P4mE5RJQuSFXx%20fwotLaiMwGGBwMgREwXLZkBZfPeQqFYqlggASvK7pZsIhTmaPCB4BSqTwdQy9Z9UKz0NZ0F10HhMJhSKRyT9%20b67RLkgBDAAOTCAA) But click Reset 1st. then stop if you like and repeat.  If you want to make it faster, notice Ic increases. Why?

- menu > options > more options ...

Verify your formulae with what you have learned so far on the scopes.  ( only 1k data points per channel.)

[Final settings for startup and remember to Reset for "Null" initial conditions](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsCmC0AcIBMYB0B2AjE9SAs8hAnPAMx6RIh6kiYR5IBQA7smIvhEpAGzJ5uTAE4hSKAdz6TwdMK2TSkhMROWJMI6uJk0q62YKYBzRfwM9%20pMHnBMA8lGwzIeW11nyAbmeQrLMhAMENae4KiQTACWqtwq4tyCsrxMAMZi8O5JpJl%20iBCYcIhYqPDopOIU8JCQ6GSkTAA2TvpJkM4GDOFgmJBkfbyMvEQ0mOjoCu2tDDoezGx6MjlZQQrLS2pJ8mwJeRnuKpo7uQaLBkfUg3tTexd4V6ezKvKCtAGwOjc6EJAA%20oO-MC-bCuXi-EpESFkXi8VxgJBIcSA1BgVGYQHA34ANQA9gBXAAuTFevgILRARH4ECI-zwGJBkFIyNRPWZvXg%20EwmUysJGkIxSF%20NKZAEkADoAZwAFAAZACUxLAb2kY34NxQ%20TEtPpPAozLRwIwkMhkCImF4pEgYBq8AFvyZoslUsEACUFSSAthEDdzUEQLaAUCQXq0Cz0bxSrUbOhGeg8JhMBUaUDBbbHRLUgBDAAOTCAA)

All drawings are rubber band wires and corner part drag/stretch/rotate

Alt. clk , also thumbwheel does more, over part values in schema only.

Comment: Lame voters -1, fail to appreciate excellence

Comment: Someone is out to get ya. If -1 means you lost 2 rep, and my +1 adds 10 rep, then you should have 8 more rep now. It's like compound interest :)